# How can a strict subset of a probability space be collectively exhaustive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the example given in this text, I am given 4 possible events in a space. Then I am told that two of the events are collectively exhaustive. How is this remotely possible?

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Everyone is either healthy or diseased.  What's the problem?

Comment: The probability space defined in the question consists of 4 events: disease present, healthy, positive test, and negative test. The union of the events healthy and disease does not result in the probability space defined thus cannot be collectively exhaustive.